# from an array to object with costume keys while converting the date

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to convert that kind of array to an object while formating the date to be able to use it with a chart.

Here is a snippet of what I did so far

```js
arr=[1524314460000,0.067872,0.067876,0.067876,0.06785,0.41500986]
var obj = {...arr}
const newKeys = {0: new Date("time"), 1: "open" , 2:"low",3:"high",4:"close",5:"volume" };
function renameKeys(obj, newKeys) {
  const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    const newKey = newKeys[key] || key;
    return { [newKey]: obj[key] };
  });
  return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
}
const renamedObj = renameKeys(obj, newKeys);
console.log(renamedObj)
```

As you can see I able to convert it to an object but I cant use `new Date()` to convert the time , Any idea on how to approach the task as you can see I am getting `invalid date`.

Thank you

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: `new Date("time")` it always `Invalid Date`  because you are passing string inside of new Date() [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: `new Date("time")` to `new Date()`  ??

Comment: I would like to passe the value of 1524314460000 to the new Date function like this new Date(1524314460000) , to get the date in a normal format not in the unix format

Comment: Use `new Date(obj[key])` @AhmedBrahimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `new Date()` from `newKeys` as you need date in the value of `time` key. Simply add a condition in the `map` that will check if the property is `time` or not. If it is, change it to date with `new Date(obj[key])`

```js
arr=[1524314460000,0.067872,0.067876,0.067876,0.06785,0.41500986]
var obj = {...arr}
const newKeys = {0: "time", 1: "open" , 2:"low",3:"high",4:"close",5:"volume" };
function renameKeys(obj, newKeys) {
  const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if(newKeys[key] === 'time'){
      obj[key] = new Date(obj[key]);
    }
    const newKey = newKeys[key] || key;
    return { [newKey]: obj[key] };
  });
  return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
}
const renamedObj = renameKeys(obj, newKeys);
console.log(renamedObj)
```

Comment: Thank you that what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly use your `Array` to convert into object using `reduce()` or `map` to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [1524314460000, 0.067872, 0.067876, 0.067876, 0.06785, 0.41500986],
 newKeys = {
  0: 'time',
  1: "open",
  2: "low",
  3: "high",
  4: "close",
  5: "volume"
};

function renameKeys(arr, newKeys) {
 return arr.reduce((r,v,i)=>{
 i = newKeys[i];
 r[i]= i == 'time'? new Date(v):v;
 return r;
  },{});
}
console.log(renameKeys(arr, newKeys))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {  max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like just using the array indexes would be enough:

```js
var arr = [1524314460000, 0.067872, 0.067876, 0.067876, 0.06785, 0.41500986]

var obj = {
  time: new Date(arr[0]),
  open: arr[1],
  low: arr[2],
  high: arr[3],
  close: arr[4],
  volume: arr[5]
}

console.log(obj)
```